# Set ENV variables using Ansible command line

Tags: python, command-line, environment-variables, ansible

I am trying to set an environment variable on my machine with Ansible. Then I would reference that in my python script. Is there a command line tag for Ansible that will set that environment variable such as:

```
ansible all -i inventory.py --env environment_name -m ping
```

I can't seem to find anything that references this particular thing. The only thing I'm able to find is how to set an environment variable through an Ansible playbook. Since I'm not using a playbook, I'm not sure how I would do this.

Answer (score 0):

We have a win_environment module for Windows, but that makes sense because Windows has a single dedicated place to store system and user envvars. It doesn't really make sense on a *nix system- how would Ansible know where to persist it (/etc/profile, .bashrc, .cshrc, .bash_profile, or any of a dozen other places)?

The playbook stuff is about setting an ephemeral envvar for a given task/play (so it's in effect while Ansible's running, but not persistent).

You could use the lineinfile module or template module to ensure it's set in a specific place, but that's probably the best you're going to be able to do...

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help.